# How to structure multiple mvc projects that share a domain model using IntelilJ

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, domain-driven-design

I'm hoping to get some advice on how to structure/setup a project.

Currently we have a webapp that uses spring, and JPA/hibernate. We want to create an admin webapp that's going to live separately then the "user" webapp for backend stuff we need to support. We want to keep it separate from the existing project so they can be deployed independently since they have different testing and reliability requirements, as well as we want to be able to iterate more quickly on the admin stuff. These are deployed via war files built by maven.

We do want them to share the domain model though, and we would prefer to keep the existing configuration from the webapp as well. So basically we want to be able to separate out the webservices from each other, while keeping everything else the same (app-context, web config, persistence, etc...).

Is there a nice way to separate out the webservices, or will we basically have to duplicate the entire project for each war file, or keep them lock step?

Comment: using symbolic links could be a good idea here. Duplication of codes is never the good way :)

Answer (score 0):

Package your domain model (entity and DAO classes) in a separate jar. Use maven for dependency management. Distribute this domain model jar in a company local repository (eg: nexus). Then on your user web-app & admin web-app just declare this as a dependency.

The only thing you need to be aware when using this mechanism is when you update the domain model and distribute new version into nexus, all downstream packages dependency version has to be updated and recompiled

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't really do what I want. I still have need to see inside of the domain model. I think git subtrees would sort of let me do what I want, but I still have to copy the web.xml/application-context.xml etc..., I think that might be the solution I have to go with. Not optimal, but it doesn't seem like any IDEs currently support my use case.

Comment: You still can see inside domain model -- but only through separate project. But yes the downside is if you update your domain model jar you have to ensure it propagate to your client project